# Mount a large squashfs in a way that allows random writes (to a separate filesystem)?

Tags: filesystems, postgresql, autofs, squashfs, overlayfs

I just received a few-dozen-gigabyte squashfs that contains a PostgreSQL database. In order to be able to conveniently query it, I need to have a write access, which makes it complicated. Is there a filesystem similar to (or a setting for) overlayfs/autofs that would enable this use case? I'm getting the impression that when I ran `select * from tbl limit 1;`, overlayfs was trying to rewrite the whole file, which is not acceptable in my situation.

Comment: Odd that it needs to write. Have you tried `default_transaction_read_only = on;` in your PostgreSQL config? Also, move the WAL logs—they may need to be writable.

Comment: @derobert: And pidfile?

Comment: Yeah, though that's tiny so you could just let overlay etc. take care of that. I'm not sure if pg can actually run w/o writing to the data files.. Also, any reason for it to be a squashfs? Could it be something typically writable like ext4 instead?

Comment: @derobert: this is what I have basically.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the project [squashmount](https://github.com/vaeth/squashmount). It mounts a directory with both a squashfs and an autofs/overlay/overlayfs system to allow for squashing ro access as well as write access. Completely configurable on how much change requires re-squashing, its a nice to use for database storage, repos spools, etc.